# parsing with simple html dom, placing the results into an array and then taking only the results that i want

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

i am pretty sure that my title maybe confused you but i have a question. simply i am parsing all the title names from the `$url` and then i print them...it works just fine **Question**: but what if i didn't want to show me the first title name and the third? Is it possible to right code to the `foreach` and say for example `don't get the first[0] and the third[2]` but take all the others title names. If yes or this is answered please redirect me cause i couldn't find something thanx.

This is my code below..

```
include 'lib/simple_html_dom.php';

$url="http://hallofbeorn.com/LotR?CardSet=The+Hunt+for+Gollum";
$html=file_get_html($url);

$array = [];

foreach ($html->find('a[style="margin-bottom:2px;font-size:medium;font-weight:bold;display:inline- 
block;"]') as $values) {
$array[] = $values->plaintext;
}

print_r($array);
```

i know that i can do it with that way: `print_r($array[1]);` `print_r($array[3]);` `print_r($array[4]);`.............etc but i am asking if there is a faster way inside the `foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `if` statement can help you:

```php
foreach ($html->find('a[style="margin-bottom:2px;font-size:medium;font-weight:bold;display:inline-block;"]') as $i => $values) {
    if($i != 0 && $i != 2) {
        $array[] = $values->plaintext;
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: of course.... sometimes it's so simple but i can't even think it. Thank you sir for your time

Answer (score 2):

You should look at regex.
Try this:

```
$url="http://hallofbeorn.com/LotR?CardSet=The+Hunt+for+Gollum";
$html=file_get_contents($url);
$pattern = '/<a href="(.*)" style="margin-bottom:2px;font-size:medium;font-weight:bold;display:inline-block;">(.*)<\/a>/m';
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);
print_r($matches[2]);
```

Comment: i know regex.. but this isn't what i am asking.. also this example is returning me errors

Comment: Sorry. I fixed script. You can use now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to fetch the data.

```
$url="http://hallofbeorn.com/LotR?CardSet=The+Hunt+for+Gollum";
$html=file_get_contents($url);
$pattern = '/(?P<cards><a href=".*" style="margin-bottom:2px;font-size:medium;font-weight:bold;display:inline-block;">.*<\/a>)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);
header('content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: This is not my question..i know how to get the data.